# Can 1 person survive this experiment?

Tags: survival

You know when scientists run decades long experiments where they create new species of bacteria in petri dishes to test them one against the other or to test them against various antibiotics and see how fast they adapt?
Our reality is nothing but a petri dish to test how humanity evolves it's behavior and shape.
Today, 2021 it's homo sapiens 10'000th generation on this reality.

It's time to test humanity with it's first challenge.

Humans from a different reality, humans from the 40'000th generation will be introduced into our reality, only 0.002% of them which is 9 billions of them, 9 billion fully armed terminators trained and bred to bring death, they will be dropped  near our planet with spaceships and self sufficient automatic farms for food and bullets.
Their job will be to kill as many humans as possible without destroying the planet and leaving as many non human animals unharmed as possible (you don't destroy the petri dish when you want to kill a colony and you don't burn down a house when trying to exterminate termites).
The 40k generation humans will be fighting for a greater good, 10k generation humans will be fighting for their lives.
40k humans are older, more evolved, more advanced and have a similar history to humanity wile also originating in a cloned planet.

This is no different than when scientists drop a lethal quantity of poison in a bacterial colony to see if at least a few of them adapt tolerance to that poison or when they drop more evolved colonies inside more primitive ones. The only difference is that bacteria can produce more generations in a week than humanity will ever produce in it's entire existence thus bacteria can adapt to things humans can't even possibly comprehend and imagine.

is it realistic for at least one human to survive this extermination experiment? is there really no heaven to escape to on this planet?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) that is open-ended, opinion-based, and subject to [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609). For additional information see both this [help/on-topic] page and this [help/dont-ask] page.

Comment: If they're all cloned then they've not evolved they've been grown. It's incredibly unclear what it is your setting consists of, one minute they're terminators, the next they're old clones.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.  Take organism A, freeze some of them in time, then let the other organism A evolve.  Then take the frozen organism A and bring it back to life and clone it...now you have organism A evolved version and organism A primitive version. We humans are nothing more than the primitive version. And yes organisms can evolve even with clonation, evolution existed before sex evolved, evolution existed when cells could only clone themselves, evolution can even happen within a single organism...that's how your antibodies work.

Comment: Fair enough, but you've not stated in the body of the question what it is that they are clones of, can you [edit] the question to clarify and to give additional parameters which might make it possible to distinguish what constitutes a best answer. At the moment it seems you've potentially got a free-for-all of opinion-based options likely to be posted.

Comment: What time frame are we talking about? And will the 40k humans depart after they finish their extermination mission?

Comment: VTO not bad actuallly, someone should have point out that humans for a long time are not about evolution, but evolution of social interaction and social building which highlights few problems with this, q. But until it closed I guess we won't have the answer.

Comment: @MolbOrg isn't psyche in the dna, thus part of normal evolution?

Comment: @user no it is not, not exactly but a similar difference between hardware and software. Brains is the result of dna, but knowledge of math or whatever is not. Brains is most flexible part of adaptation feature of humans.

Answer (score 1):

**The 40k humans die due to artillery and air support.**

A lot of people would die, but humanity can throw a lot of firepower at people it doesn't like. Heavy artillery, bombs, and nuclear weapons would exterminate the terminators, and ensure the survival of more militaristic nations.

Flesh is weak. No amount of breeding will let humans stand up to explosive artillery shells. The more advanced gun wielding people will be destroyed from miles away.

Comment: Did you notice how many attackers there are? The "40K" refers to how many generations passed in their evolution and technological development (compared to our "10K" today). The number of attackers is ***9 billion,*** with is about 1.5 billion more than the total world population today. Considering we'd have trouble wiping out our entire population today with nuclear weapons....

Comment: I did notice that number. It would strain supply lines, but killing that many people is certainly doable. I said 40k because they probably meant space marine like people.

Comment: Nothing to do with warhammer 40k.